# App Store - Identify users who purchased a subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

When using subscriptions in iOS via in-app purchases is there anyway for me to identify users who have purchased the app?

For instance, if I have an Android app as well how can I ensure an iOS user moving to the Android app doesn't have to re-purchase a subscription?

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Maybe you should read the [App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies) before trying anything. If your user's purchases outside of your app can unlock things in your app, you are most likely to get rejeted.

Comment: I'm using in-app purchases, I want to identify the users who have made a purchase so they don't have to purchase on Android as well.

Comment: I thinks **11.3** applies to your case : **Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected**

Comment: So a user must purchase a subscription twice, once for iOS and again for Android.