# Suitable payment method for sell Credits in iOS, Android and Web

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, google-play, in-app-billing

I am developing a system it has web application, iOS application and Android application. There user can buy credits through web, iOS device or Android device. Credit purchased are stored in Database and can be used from any of Applications mentioned above. My Question is in mobile Apps should I use In App Purchase and In App billing or should use third party Payment Gateway. I contacted Google and Apple. I didn't get direct answer. I was asked to look at the web.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23897158/317461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't use 3rd party for purchasing credits that are used within the app. My app just got rejected for that reason. I used Swipe instead of IAP